# No Wireless on Thinkpad T41 with Ubuntu 12

Tags: wireless, thinkpad, atheros

I just installed Ubuntu 12 on my old Thinkpad T41. I've done this once before but back then I installed Ubuntu 11 first and upgraded to 12. This time I''ve used the Mini iso file.

Before the wireless worked perfectly without any tweaks, but now, it's checked off as enabled in the notification area, but I can't see any wireless networks.

If I do `nm-tool` I can see that for the device `wlan0`, the driver `ath5k` is used, but it has `state: unmanaged`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (kind of) solved this be installing Ubuntu 10, and then upgrading my way up till latest version (12.04). Now everything seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf` and change:

`Managed=false`

to

`Managed=true`

Comment: The file doesn't exist, but I can find the a file called "NetworkManager.conf", with the contents:

    [ifupdown]
    managed=false

Comment: And that didn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign any static ip address for your wireless card earlier?

You can check/edit `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: Just check and no, I did not. There's nothing about "static" or any ip-addresses here.